# Bash history size on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: linux, bash

Goal: Increase Bash History to above 1000 commands

Problem: Bash is clearing history once it hits 1000 commands

I want to save old commands I type into Amazon Linux Console. I couldn't find the configuration file for Amazon Linux Bash .bashrc etc.

What is the easiest way to increase the number of Bash commands in history on Amazon Linux 2?

Comment: Check out HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE ([Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#Bash-Variables)).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure this for your personal needs, edit `.bash_profile` in your home directory to add

```sh
export HISTFILESIZE=10000
```

at the end of the file (or, of course, whichever number makes sense for you).

If you want to configure this system-wide for all user accounts which use Bash as their shell, you'll want to modify `/etc/bash`, ideally inside the section with a conditional which starts with the comment "are we an interactive shell?"

Remarkably, contrary to my expectation, Bash does not already `export` this variable for you by itself.